# Issues splitting a string into 2 halves in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, split, strtok

I have a string that contains with spaces, such as "print 2" or "print 3 test". I'm trying to remove the first argument - in these examples, the print.

I tried strtok():

```
char *test;
test = strtok(COMMAND, " ");
printf("%s\n", test);
```

However printing test will segfault. I tried making a function, and it works fine from main() but when called from the function I need it in, it also segfaults.

```
char* split(char S[], int N) {
    printf("Running split() on %s\n", S);
    int Spaces = 1;
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i<strlen(S) && Spaces <=N; i++) {
        if (S[i] == ' ') {
            Spaces++;
        }
    }
    printf("split: %s\n", &S[i]);
    //return "0";
    return &S[i];
}
```

I'm guessing it's some kind of pointer problem. Command is being passed into the print function like so:

```
Print(File, Lines, COMMAND);
```

Comment: Well you never initialize test so you can't access it with strtok.

Comment: Initializing it with an empty and populated string both have the segfault.

Comment: Is COMMAND initialized? And does it contain " "?

Comment: I take it your first snippet of code is from a function called `Print`; so can we see how its definition begins? (In particular, I'm wondering exactly how you declare `COMMAND`, which seems to exist in two versions, one in `Print` and one in whatever calls `Print`.) And can we see how the `COMMAND` passed into the `Print` function gets its value? Everything you've described is consistent with that variable having a wrong value -- e.g., a null pointer or a pointer to something other than a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Sterling it contains a string, potentially with spaces, like "print 2".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan : void Print(char File[120][80], int Lines, char* Command) {

Comment: That's `Command`, with one capital letter. But you're using `COMMAND`, all capital letters. Is that a global variable, or something? And (I'm afraid I'm repeating myself, but you didn't answer this bit) how does `COMMAND` get its value?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code just in case passing a variable in without changing the name was the problem. Command was previously COMMAND. It gets its value from fgets in main(): fgets(COMMAND, 100, stdin);

Comment: @Alexandra: How is `COMMAND` declared?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what COMMAND is in your test sample, but you should test, if strtok returns null (when strtok can't find a token).
printf with a nullpointer will give you a seg vault.

Normally you call strtok from a loop:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: +1 for `printing with a nullpointer will give you a seg fault`

Answer (score 0):

always test the return value of strtok()!

If no such byte (2nd parameter) is found, ie. no tokens exist in the string pointed to by the 1st parameter, a null pointer is returned.